# How to generate TOC by custom labels at appended documents' beginnings?

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, pdf

I am appending documents of many pages, but would like to have links to the beginnings of each document first page in TOC. 
Pseudocode for making custom TOC

1. Add custom label at the first page of pdf documents
2. Add custom labels to TOC

Code which adds pagenumbering on pages without decreasing size of pdf-pages, but does nothing to the application of references at the beginning of pdf-pages

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for links in TOC
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56316/13173
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Werner, remove top margin border
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338919/13173
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\oldincludepdf\includepdf
\renewcommand{\includepdf}[2][]{%
  \oldincludepdf[pagecommand={‌​\thispagestyle{fancy‌​}},#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

% TODO add custom labels to TOC 
\tableofcontents
% Pseudocode
% \addcontentsline{toc}{someLabelForPdf}{\listPdfBeginningLabels}

% TODO add here a label/... to the beginning of pdf page such that included in TOC
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{7.pdf}
% No reference to the rest
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{7.pdf}

% TODO reference here
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{8.pdf}
% No reference to the rest
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{8.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Maybe pseudocode `\addcontentsline{toc}{someLabelForPdf}{\listPdfBeginningLabels}` can work.

Example TOC

```
Table of Contents
7               1
8               150
```

### Trying Samcarter's proposal

[Manual](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf#page=7) where Samcarter is poiting to is about the following `addtotoc` so I try the following but I get the following output

```
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain},addtotoc={1}]{7.pdf}
```

Output

```
<use  "7.pdf" > <use  "7.pdf" > <use  "7.pdf"  page1> <use  "7.pdf"  page1>
[1] <use  "7.pdf"  page1> <use  "7.pdf"  page1>
Runaway argument?
addtotoc={1}]{9.pdf} \includepdf [pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \AM@parse@toclisti was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.33
```

[Manual](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf#page=7)

```
addtotoc Adds an entry to the table of contents. This option requires five
arguments, separated by commas:
addtotoc={hpage number i,hsection i,hlevel i,hheading i,hlabel i}
```

### Iterating Christian's proposal

No need to separate by `pages=1` and `pages=2-`. 
Some minor cosmetic changes in links

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56316/13173
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Werner, remove top margin border
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338919/13173
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\oldincludepdf\includepdf
\renewcommand{\includepdf}[4][]{%
  \oldincludepdf[pagecommand={‌​\thispagestyle{fancy‌​}},addtotoc={#4,section,1,#2,#3}, #1]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{8.pdf}{p1d8}{1}
\end{document}
```

OS: Debian 8.7
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UB
Test file `7.pdf`: http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf
Test file `8.pdf`: http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf

Comment: see `pdfpages` documentation, section "Hypertext options" and "Experimental options"

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: Can you provide us with some testing file `7.pdf` or shall we invent some? ;-)

Comment: Since `addtotoc` is tricky, one must provide the correct information, which is actually 5 parameters. Shall this be added as 5 additional arguments to `\includepdf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `addtotoc` option is a little bit tricky!

`addtotoc={page-number,sectiontype,level,heading,label}` is the correct usage of `addtotoc`,

where the page number **must** match the page number that is given with the `pages=` option.

- sectiontype can be `section`, `subsection` etc.
- level is the section level, i.e. 1 means `section`, 2 stands for `subsection` etc. (as usual)
- heading is the name that appears in the ToC
- label is the label that is applied to this included pdf file (can be left empty

---

The `7.pdf` and `8.pdf` have been generated with following file (and renamed)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Beginning \jobname}
\blindtext[50]
\end{document}
```

Here's the running code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for links in TOC
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56316/13173
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Werner, remove top margin border
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338919/13173
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\oldincludepdf\includepdf
\renewcommand{\includepdf}[4][]{%
  \oldincludepdf[pagecommand={‌​\thispagestyle{fancy‌​}},addtotoc={#4,section,1,#2,#3}, #1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

% TODO add custom labels to TOC 
\tableofcontents
% Pseudocode
% \addcontentsline{toc}{someLabelForPdf}{\listPdfBeginningLabels}

% TODO add here a label/... to the beginning of pdf page such that included in TOC
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{7.pdf}{firstpage7pdf}{1}
% No reference to the rest
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{7.pdf}{remainingpages7pdf}{2}

% TODO reference here
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{8.pdf}{firstpage8pdf}{1}
% No reference to the rest
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{8.pdf}{remainginpages8pdf}{2}

\end{document}
```

**Update with key-value interface**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Switch to expl3 - Syntax

% Define a storing place for the option values
\prop_new:N \l_leo_option_prop

% keys for the new functionality
\keys_define:nn {LEO} {%
   page .code:n = {\prop_put:Nnn \l_leo_option_prop {page} {#1}},
  section .code:n = {\prop_put:Nnn \l_leo_option_prop {section} {#1}},
  level .code:n = {\prop_put:Nnn \l_leo_option_prop {level} {#1}},
  heading .code:n = {\prop_put:Nnx \l_leo_option_prop {heading} {#1}},
  label .code:n = {\prop_put:Nnn \l_leo_option_prop {label} {#1}},
}

%  Keys setting 
\cs_new:Npn \SetupPdfInclude #1 {%
  \keys_set:nn {LEO} {#1}
}

% Get some key value 
\cs_new:Npn \retrieveoption #1 {%
  \prop_item:Nn \l_leo_option_prop {#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for links in TOC
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56316/13173
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Werner, remove top margin border
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338919/13173
\usepackage{letltxmacro}


\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\pdfpages@@includepdf\includepdf

\RenewDocumentCommand{\includepdf}{O{}mo}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfValueTF{#3}{% Is there a 3rd argument? Yes
    % Process the keys for the \includepdf first in order to get the value of 'pages=...' option
    % This is stored to \AM@pagestemp (see pdfpages.sty)
    \setkeys{pdfpages}{#1}%
    \SetupPdfInclude{label={label#2\AM@pagestemp},page={\AM@pagestemp}, heading={#2},#3}
    % Call the old command with the options for addtotoc
    \pdfpages@@includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},addtotoc={\retrieveoption{page},\retrieveoption{section},\retrieveoption{level},\retrieveoption{heading},\retrieveoption{label}},#1]{#2}
  }{% No, no 3rd. argument}
    \pdfpages@@includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},#1]{#2}
  }%
  \endgroup% Prevent leaking of key values to the next call of the command
}
\makeatother



% Set some default values
\SetupPdfInclude{page=1,section=section,level=1}

\begin{document}

% TODO add custom labels to TOC 
\tableofcontents
% Pseudocode
% \addcontentsline{toc}{someLabelForPdf}{\listPdfBeginningLabels}

\includepdf[pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{7.pdf}[label=firstpage7pdf]
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{7.pdf}[page=2,heading={\retrieveoption{heading} continued}]

\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{8.pdf}[label=firstpage8pdf]
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{8.pdf}[heading={\retrieveoption{heading} continued}]

\end{document}
```

The several key-values correspond to the entries in the `addtotoc` option, the advantage is, that the precise order is done by the code, not by usage specification.

By default `heading` will use the mandatory argument of `\includepdf`, i.e. `#2`.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: You can give an empty label, if `remainingpages` troubles you ;-)

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: Well, you have made the distinction between first page and pages=2 in your original code, for whatever reasons.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: I would personally use a totally different style of the `\includepdf` macro. One user wants to have version A and scolds me of having provided version B or vice versa...

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: Updated

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: In fact, you **do** need the label for the addtotoc option since `pdfpages` adds an empty label (if this occurs more than once, LaTeX complains about multiple identical label (being empty then). In order to prevent this, I've added a standard label then.

Comment: Can you please explain about the ideas behind key expansion etc  `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\prop_new:N \l_leo_option_prop`. It seems to be very functional which I like a lot. - - I altered the last commands to `\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{7.pdf}[page=1,label=firstpage7pdf]; \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{8.pdf}[page=1,label=firstpage8pdf]`, simply which does not seem to cause any conflicts.